# Chatroom bug. Message was posted but it is still showing that message is not posted yet

Tags: bug, chat

I posted a message in a room, but it failed to post and shows me:

> You can perform this action in 1 second retry/edit/cancel.

[image]

Strangely enough the message **GOT** posted because another user replied to it.
Check the last message, the second last message was a reply to this message. [Permalink to the message.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3721504#3721504)

It should be either way:

- Or I should retry if the message failed to get processed by the server
- Or I should not get an error if the message got processed

Both situations for the same message feels like something is broken.

Comment: @rene But I didn't re-posted it or edit the message. This was a fresh message and it seems like the message was throttled, but the other user just replied to that message which shouldn't be possible in that case.

Comment: @rene Can you suggest edit please? I don't know what else to write.

Comment: Just for the record, with over 2K one can't suggest edits, just perform a full edit. (which the OP can then roll back)

Comment: *throws records at @ShadowWizard *

Comment: Boo! Do you get this ping?